# How to add timer to each divide screen in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, screen, split-screen-multitasking

I created one window and split it into 3 different windows. I want to add a clock to each screen, that does not depend on the other clocks.
my code opens 2 window- one is the timer and the second one is the window that i split to 3 windows.

```
    from tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk


class split_screen(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="", width=10,fg="black", bg ="red", font="david 18 bold underline")
        self.label.pack()
        self.remaining = 0
        self.countdown(1000)
        self.configure(background="black")


    def screen(self):
        root = Tk()
        root.geometry("650x700")
        root.configure(bg='black')
        root.title("test")
        left = Frame(root, borderwidth=200, relief="solid")
        right = Frame(root, borderwidth=20, relief="solid")
        box3 = Frame(right, borderwidth=2, relief="solid")
        box1 = Frame(left, borderwidth=2, relief="solid")
        box2 = Frame(left, borderwidth=2, relief="solid")

        label1 = Label(box3, text="winner's" + "\n\n\n" + "Player 1",fg= "black", bg = "red", font = "david 18 bold underline")
        label2 = Label(box1, text="Computer 1",fg = "black", bg = "red", font= "david 18 bold underline")
        label3 = Label(box2, text="Computer 2",fg = "black", bg = "red", font= "david 18 bold underline")

        left.pack(side="left", expand=True, fill="both")
        right.pack(side="right", expand=True, fill="both")

        box3.pack(expand=True, fill="both", padx=10, pady=10)
        box1.pack(expand=True, fill="both", padx=10, pady=10)
        box2.pack(expand=True, fill="both", padx=10, pady=10)

        label1.pack()
        label2.pack()
        label3.pack()


    def countdown(self, remaining = None):
        if remaining is not None:
            self.remaining = remaining

        if self.remaining <= 0:
            self.label.configure(text="time's up!")
        else:
            self.label.configure(text="%d" % self.remaining)
            self.remaining = self.remaining - 1
            self.after(1000, self.countdown)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = split_screen()
    app.screen()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should not be creating more than one instance of `Tk`. Any solution built on that design will have extra problems.

Comment: @BryanOakley So i can not add clock to each split screen without making any extra problems?

Comment: No, I didn't say clock, I said "instance of `Tk`". You should only ever have a single instance of `Tk`, but you have two instances.

Comment: @BryanOakley Ok. so can you guide me with that?

Comment: additional windows need to be instances of `Toplevel`.

Comment: but i only need one window witch is split to 3 windows. why do i need to use 'Toplevel'

Comment: I don't know why you need to use `Toplevel`. You're using two instances of `Tk`, so I assume you want two windows.

Comment: That's true, but i don't want to use two instances of  `Tk`. 
I did it for an example. i only need to add to each window in the split window a timer.

Comment: we can only go by the code that you post. If the code you posted creates two windows, we have to assume you want to create two windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did multiple changes :
As Bryan Oakley said, don't create multiple instances of Tk(). You also don't need to import tkinter twice.

```
import tkinter as tk


class split_screen(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.geometry("650x700")
        self.configure(bg='black')
        self.title("test")
        left = tk.Frame(self, borderwidth=200, relief="solid")
        right = tk.Frame(self, borderwidth=20, relief="solid")
        box1 = tk.Frame(left, borderwidth=2, relief="solid")
        box2 = tk.Frame(left, borderwidth=2, relief="solid")
        box3 = tk.Frame(right, borderwidth=2, relief="solid")

        label1 = tk.Label(box3, text="winner's" + "\n\n\n" + "Player 1",fg= "black", bg = "red", font = "david 18 bold underline")
        label2 = tk.Label(box1, text="Computer 1",fg = "black", bg = "red", font= "david 18 bold underline")
        label3 = tk.Label(box2, text="Computer 2",fg = "black", bg = "red", font= "david 18 bold underline")

        clock1 = Clock(box1, 1000)
        clock2 = Clock(box2, 2000)
        clock3 = Clock(box3, 1300)

        left.pack(side="left", expand=True, fill="both")
        right.pack(side="right", expand=True, fill="both")

        box3.pack(expand=True, fill="both", padx=10, pady=10)
        box1.pack(expand=True, fill="both", padx=10, pady=10)
        box2.pack(expand=True, fill="both", padx=10, pady=10)

        label1.pack()
        label2.pack()
        label3.pack()


class Clock():
    def __init__(self, frame, count):
        self.frame = frame
        self.label = tk.Label(frame, text="", width=10,fg="black", bg ="red", font="david 18 bold underline")
        self.label.pack()
        self.remaining = 0
        self.countdown(count)
        frame.configure(background="black")

    def countdown(self, remaining = None):
        if remaining is not None:
            self.remaining = remaining

        if self.remaining <= 0:
            self.label.configure(text="time's up!")
        else:
            self.label.configure(text="%d" % self.remaining)
            self.remaining = self.remaining - 1
            self.frame.after(1000, self.countdown)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = split_screen()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution -- and arguably the best -- is to create a class that represents a single timer. You can then make as many instances as you want. This is precisely the sort of thing that classes are for: to encapsulate some behavior inside an object.

Since you're using a label to display the time, you can either have the timer class inherit from `Label`, or you can pass the label in when creating the timer.

Here's an example which inherits from `tk.Label`:

```
import tkinter as tk

class TimerLabel(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.after_id = None
        self.remaining = None

    def countdown(self, seconds):
        if seconds <= 0:
            self.configure(text="Time's up!")
        else:
            self.configure(text=f"{seconds}")
            self.after_id = self.after(1000, self.countdown, seconds-1)

    def stop(self):
        if self.after_id:
            self.configure(text="cancelled")
            self.after_cancel(self.after_id)
```

Using the above class definition, you can create as many timer widgets as you want. Here's an example that creates three:

```
root = tk.Tk()

timer1 = TimerLabel(root, width=10)
timer2 = TimerLabel(root, width=10)
timer3 = TimerLabel(root, width=10)

timer1.pack(side="top", padx=20)
timer2.pack(side="top", padx=20)
timer3.pack(side="top", padx=20)

timer1.countdown(30)
timer2.countdown(20)
timer3.countdown(10)

root.mainloop()
```